# Подобрать формулу по входящим и исходящим данным

Tags: функции

есть таблица выгруженная из одного из приложений Advantage от Baker Hughes, задача имея ряд входных и выходных данных  подобрать формулы по которым считает данное приложение
Частично разобралась но есть такие поля в которых не выходит это сделать
Возможно проще как-то открыть .exe и посмотреть там ?

Comment: Вряд ли. Вы хоть раз exe открывали:-)? Если нет, то откройте и посмотрите. Заодно почитайте в интернете, что такое exe (просто шестнадцатиричные (или большей разрядности) коды в общем случае).

Comment: Та не открывала, тут задачка а принципе то в экселе но не выходит некоторые показатели рассчитать

Comment: Reverse engineering вам в помощь:-) (не пытайтесь сделать самостоятельно)

Comment: на фрилансе брала задачку, вот и так и эдак крутила, глядя на график зависимости входных и выходных данных, почти получилось , но не получается универсальную формулу подобрать непонятно откуда «растут ноги»

Comment: Смотря что за данные. Может там машинное обучение какое-нибудь помогло бы. А может и нет